# How to run the SPFX source code downloaded from git hub?

Tags: spfx-webparts, web-partmodern-w

i have downloaded a modern webpart spfx source code from git hub and installed the **git ** inside the solder but unable to run . please help me

and also i have installed the webpart with the same name and copied the source files, but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Inside git source code you will find the readme.txt file. Please read this file and install all prerequisite that mentioned on file.
After installation you have to execute below command one by one on console.

```
gulp trust-dev-cert
gulp server
```

Now you can preview spfx web part as SharePoint workbench

You can refer this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you sure you have git and nmp installed on your local computer. Than follow these steps to run it on workbench: ( You have to run these commands one by one in the same order)

1. Clone the repository :

**Command**:  git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY

2. Install all dependencies:

**Command**: npm install

3. Now execute the commands as mentioned by @Bharat

Hope that helps!

Comment: i have installed the npm, but getting errors `node_modules\@microsoft\sp-loader\node_modules\@types\react\index.d.ts(3591,24): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exportedmember 'SVGProps'.` it belong to the npm package . and over there 470+ errors